# Filtering OpenGraph requests for photos by tag

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Given the following OpenGraph request:
/me/photos?fields=name_tags,tags.fields(id),id&type=tagged

(Returns all the images I am tagged in)

How do I tell FB to only return the images that another friend is tagged in?

Comment: try changing the /me/ to the /friend's id/ ?

Comment: That would give me all the tagged photos of said friend, no? I want only photos where both me and my friend are tagged.

Comment: Maybe do something similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7527352/1628782

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it actually does work! However, I was looking for a solution for OpenGraph.